# Kafka Streams. Global Store metrics: how can I detect consumer lag using standard metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

May be I do something wrong but I can't find any useful information about Global Store state in standard metrics of global-consumer or global-processor.

E.g. if I work with consumer api in standard way I can see lag info for consumer group, but in case of global store consumer there is no consumer group and I can't understand is my Global Store is updated or not.

Certainly I can implement my own metrics by adding logic to updater processor where I will save last handled offset for partitions. But may be there is standard way to detect and monitor lag?